# Red Black Tree based Dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, unordered-map, ordereddict

I'm trying to use python build a `Curve` class. In my design, the underlying set of points is better to be implemented in an ordered dict, just like what I have done in C++ with (ordered) map based on the red black tree (RBT). The benefits are a lot, no duplicated points, and the points are ordered by x-axis very well, etc.

While I found in python, both the `OrderedDict` and the new `Dict` (after 3.6) are just ordered by the insert order, rather than the data itself. So is there any good method to make the REAL ordered dict in python? RBT is not necessary, but I think this implementation might be a good answer. Or maybe you can convince me another design of the `Curve` is good either?

Comment: You mean [*sorted* dict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html)?

Comment: @Manuel thanks! I think that solves the problem.